# Basic expression mangling question

Tags: calculus, statistics, physics

I am looking at the solution of a physics/statistics hybrid exercise, and I can't figure out how one expression step took place.

I have that

$${dx \over dt} = gt$$

$$T = \sqrt{2h \over g}$$

where $g$ is gravity acceleration, $h$ is the height of free fall, $dx$ is a distance interval, $dt$ is the corresponding time interval and $T$ is the full duration of the fall. I want the probability of finding the free falling object at a given position interval when piking a random time during its trajectory. So it starts with the probability of picking some time interval $dt$ of the full duration time $T$:

$${dt \over T} = {dx \over gt}\sqrt{{g \over 2h}}$$

So far, so good, then comes the step I fail to understand:

$${dx \over gt}\sqrt{{g \over 2h}} = {1 \over 2 \sqrt{hx}}dx$$

Could someone please explain this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They integrated the first equation to get $x=\frac 12 gt^2$, which is valid as long as $x(0)=0$.  Then they multiplied by $1=\frac {t\sqrt g}{\sqrt {2x}}$